# Python: if first element is equal tuple together other elements

Tags: python, tuples

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find it. If I have something like:

```
lst = [(('a', 'b'), 1, 2), (('a', 'b'), 3, 4), (('b', 'c'), 5, 6)]
```

and I want to obtain a shorter list:

```
new = [(('a', 'b'), (1, 3), (2, 4)), (('b', 'c'), 5, 6)]
```

so that it groups together the other elements in a tuple by first matching element, what is the fastest way to go about it?

Comment: The elements also appear to be reordered, is that intended? (Don't use `list` as a variable name, it overwrites the Python `list()` command)

Comment: So you are grouping based on the first element? Are groups always consecutive, or can matching tuples occur anywhere?

Comment: If you mean it has to be ((a,b),(1,3),(2,4)) instead of  ((a,b),(3,1),(4,2)) or jumbled up, yes I want in in the order it comes. Matching tuple can occur anywhere, my actual list is very long with a lot of matching first element that I want to group together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are *grouping*, based on a key. If your input groups are always consecutive, you can use `itertools.groupby()`, otherwise use a dictionary to group the elements. If order matters, use a dictionary that preserves insertion order (> Python 3.6 `dict` or `collections.OrderedDict`).

Using `groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

new = [(k, *zip(*(t[1:] for t in g))) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

The above uses Python 3 syntax to interpolate tuple elements from an iterable (..., *iterable)`.

Using a dictionary:

```
groups = {}
for key, *values in lst:
    groups.setdefault(key, []).append(values)
new = [(k, *zip(*v)) for k, v in groups.items()]
```

In Python 3.6 or newer, that'll preserve the input order of the groups.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [(('a', 'b'), 1, 2), (('a', 'b'), 3, 4), (('b', 'c'), 5, 6)]
>>> [(k, *zip(*(t[1:] for t in g))) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]
[(('a', 'b'), (1, 3), (2, 4)), (('b', 'c'), (5,), (6,))]
>>> groups = {}
>>> for key, *values in lst:
...     groups.setdefault(key, []).append(values)
...
>>> [(k, *zip(*v)) for k, v in groups.items()]
[(('a', 'b'), (1, 3), (2, 4)), (('b', 'c'), (5,), (6,))]
```

If you are using Python 2, you'd have to use:

```
new = [(k,) + tuple(zip(*(t[1:] for t in g))) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter(0))]
```

or

```
from collections import OrderedDict
groups = OrderedDict()
for entry in lst:
    groups.setdefault(entry[0], []).append(entry[1:])
new = [(k,) + tuple(zip(*v)) for k, v in groups.items()]
```

Comment: Many thanks - would syntax be different if I'm using Python 2?

Comment: @ru111: added Py2 options. You really want to consider switching to Python 3 however, Python 2 is a legacy language now.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group your tuple keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(('a', 'b'), 1, 2), (('a', 'b'), 3, 4), (('b', 'c'), 5, 6)]

d = defaultdict(tuple)
for tup, fst, snd in lst:
    d[tup] += fst, snd
# defaultdict(<class 'tuple'>, {('a', 'b'): (1, 2, 3, 4), ('b', 'c'): (5, 6)})

for key, value in d.items():
    d[key] = value[0::2], value[1::2]
# defaultdict(<class 'tuple'>, {('a', 'b'): ((1, 3), (2, 4)), ('b', 'c'): ((5,), (6,))})

result = [(k, v1, v2) for k, (v1, v2) in d.items()]
```

Which Outputs:

```
[(('a', 'b'), (1, 3), (2, 4)), (('b', 'c'), (5,), (6,))]
```

**The logic of the above code:**

- Group the tuples into a `defaultdict` of tuples.
- Split the values into firsts and seconds with slicing `[0::2]` and `[1::2]`.
- Wrap this updated dictionary into the correct tuple structure with a list comprehension.

Comment: Isn't using += for immutable tuples pretty messy compared to appending to lists? Since you're unpacking anyway, it might be cleaner to use lists and convert to tuple once.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you might find using a dictionary or defaultdict more useful. It will scale better too.

```
from collections import defaultdict
listmaker = lambda: ([],[]) # makes a tuple of 2 lists for the values.
my_data = defaultdict(listmaker) 
for letter_tuple, v1, v2 in lst:
    my_data[letter_tuple][0].append(v1)
    my_data[letter_tuple][1].append(v2)
```

Then you’ll get a new tuple of lists for each unique `(x,y)` key. Python handles the checking to see if the key already exists and it’s fast. If you absolutely need it to be a list, you can always convert it too:

```
new = [(k, tuple(v1s), tuple(v2s)) for k, (v1s, v2s) in my_data.items()]
```

This list comprehension is a bit opaque, but it will unpack your dictionary into the form specified `[(('a', 'b'), (1,3), (2,4)), ... ]`

Comment: Your tuple grouping is (1, 2), (3, 4) instead of (1, 3), (2, 4)